# Simulate Universal Bootloader (DAS U-BOOT) with Qemu

Tags: boot, pulseaudio, virtualization

I was trying to simulate u-boot with qemu for the ARM based versatile_pb board.
I was successfully able to CROSS_COMPILE my u-boot source code with the `gcc-linaro-arm-none-eabi-toolchain` and create binary files.
But when I try to simulate it with qemu using the following command:

```
**$ qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel u-boot.bin**
```

the u-boot prompt does not show up, instead i get the following error:

```
**pulseaudio: set_sink_input_volume() failed
pulseaudio: Reason: Invalid argument
pulseaudio: set_sink_input_mute() failed
pulseaudio: Reason: Invalid argument**
```

I tried reinstalling pulseaudio on my system but didn't do any good.

I hope that you all can help me out for I am new to this.

Thanks
Ashijeet